# Component "variables" not set, not passed to forceCanvas

Tags: lightning-aura-components, lightning, lightning-web-components, canvas

I'm trying to host a canvas app on a Lightning page.  The canvas app itself needs the current record and type in order to load things on my own server properly.  I have the canvas app up and working (decrypting the SignedRequest), but the parameters aren't passed in.  Its driving me bonkers.

What seems real funny is if I call `cmp.set("foo", "bar")`, then calling `cmp.get("foo")` returns *undefined*.

Can anyone help figure out what's going on?  Why isn't `cmp.set()` working?  Or is that a red herring, and I have something wrong in my `.cmp`?

Here's my current code, debug stuff and all.

component.cmp

```
<aura:component implements="flexipage:availableForRecordHome,force:hasRecordId,force:hasSObjectName" access="global" >
    <aura:handler name="init" value="{!this}" action="{!c.doInit}"/>
  
    Parameters: <ui:outputText value="{!v.nowork}" />
    
    <force:canvasApp applicationName="My Magical App"
                     developerName="My_Magical_App" 
                     parameters="{!v.parameters}"
                     width="100%"
                     />

</aura:component>
```

controller.js

```
({
     doInit : function(cmp) {
        //var parameters = '{"objectId":"' + component.get("v.recordId") + '", "objectType":"' + component.get("v.sObjectName") + '"}';
         
        var recordId = cmp.get("v.recordId");
        var objectType = cmp.get("v.sObjectName");
        
         var json = JSON.stringify({
             recordId: recordId,
             objectType: objectType
         });
         
         alert(json);
         
        cmp.set("v.nowork", "hi mom");
        cmp.set("v.parameters", json);
        cmp.set("v.label","This is a label");
        var label = cmp.get("v.label");

        alert(label);
    }
})
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As written, I'd expect an error to happen early. You can't write to an attribute you don't have access to, and this can cause exceptions.

```
cmp.set("v.nowork", "hi mom");
```

I don't see an attribute called `nowork`, so I expect this line to be the culprit. Make sure you're only setting attributes that are defined in your markup, or if in a related component, that is at least "public" (within your own code) or "global" (within someone else's namespace).

Similarly, doing `cmp.set("foo", "bar")` would also fail, because there's no Value Provider called "foo" that would provide a default key. You need to be very careful about which value providers you're accessing (`c`, `v`, `$Label`, etc).

Answer (score 0):

Points to @sfdcfox for the high level answer, but to make it painfully, explicitly clear to others like me who don't eat, breathe, and poop Salesforce:

You must declare an attribute for any "local" variables you use.  In my component I had to add this:

```
<aura:component implements="flexipage:availableForRecordHome,force:hasRecordId,force:hasSObjectName" 
                access="global" >
    
    <aura:attribute name="parameters" type="String" />    <!-- Declare parameters! -->
```

Now I can access it via `cmp.get('v.parameters');` and `cmp.set('v.parameters', 'Fizz buzz!');`